# How to take a screenshot with xcb?

Tags: c++, c, linux, x11, xcb

I am trying to take a screenshot using xcb. There are no examples at all and xcb lacks documentation.

Note: I have a working version with cairo, but it is slow for my purpose.

So, how to take a screenshot with xcb in pure C?

Comment: You capture the root window content.

Comment: I need the code :)

Comment: `xcb_get_image` on the root window. However, I doubt that using XCB would be faster than using cairo. What makes you think that cairo is too slow?

Comment: What I'm doing is writing a window manager in objective-c with XCB. Actually I'm writing XCBKit, a SDK to implements window managers in objective-c and interact with X11.
Actually when the user icnoify a window, the WM creates a preview of the window making a screenshots, iconifies the window, and in the iconified, WM puts the scaled image. It works quite well, is not scaling that is slow but taking the screenshot of a maximized window that is slow but still accetable. I work on a MacBook late 2009
https://github.com/AlessandroSangiuliano/XcbKit/blob/develop/XCBKit/utils/CairoDrawer.m#L215